# Calling function from different files in C++ error

Tags: c++

I would like to use one function from Stats.cpp in Application.cpp.  Here are my code snippets:

In Stats.h:

```
#ifndef STATS_H
#define STATS_H

class Stats
{
public:
    void generateStat(int i);
};

#endif
```

In Stats.cpp:

```
#include Stats.h
void generateStat(int i)
{
    //some process code here
}
```

In Application.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    generateStat(10);
}
```

I get an "unresolved external symbol" error however I don't know what I else I would need to include in order for Application.cpp.  Any thoughts?

Comment: This is funny... The call `generateStat(10)` seems to be accepted by the compiler without any previous declaration. Is that C++?

Answer (score 2):

In **Stats.cpp**

you need to define `generateStat` like following :

```
#include Stats.h
void Stats:: generateStat(int i) // Notice the syntax, use of :: operator
{
    //some process code here
}
```

Then create object of class `Stats`, use it to call the public member function `generateStat`

```
Stats s;
s.generateStat( 10 ) ;
```

Build the application using :

`g++ -o stats Stats.cpp Application.cpp -I.`

Answer (score 0):

`generateStat` is part of your `Stats` class. You need to instantiate a `Stats` object (along with the necessary includes for `Stats.h` in your `main` class)

For example,

```
Stats stat;
stat.generateStat(i);
```

Also, your function definition needs to include the class name `Stats::generateStat`.

Answer (score 0):

The same error msg occured 2 weeks ago (at work).

At first glance --- Try:

```
 void Stats::generateStat(int i) {
     //some process code here }
```

The class name was missing. Hence, **unresolved**.

btw Concerning your header --- another issue, this #ifndef directive should not be necessary cause you should declare Stats only once in a namespace.

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H
#include "Class.h"
#endif
```

This is a generic example - Usable in cpp files.

EDIT: Now, I saw your **invocation** (main method in your case). You need an object instance to invoke your method.

```
Stats* stats = new Stats(); //add a default constructor if not done
stats->generateStat(77);

// any other stats stuff ......
// in posterior to the last use
delete(stats);
```

In your header:

```
Stats::Stats(){}; //with an empty body - no need to write it again in the cpp file
```

Comment: You have a few issues with this code, better check it over.

Comment: @codah what are u talking about?

Comment: Firstly `Stats stats` should be `Stats* stats`. And then you would have to change `stats.generateStat` to `stats->generateStat`. Why not just create it on the stack anyway? And you didn't delete it (might as well show that if you're going to advocate creating on the heap).

Comment: @codah +1 && yes, did not focus on that